# Ползунок полосы прокрутки возвращается в начальное положение после действия С++

Tags: c++, winapi, прокрутка

```
// WindowsProject1.cpp : Определяет точку входа для приложения.
//

#include "framework.h"
#include "WindowsProject1.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string> 

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Глобальные переменные:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // текущий экземпляр
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // Текст строки заголовка
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // имя класса главного окна
static long long currentScrollPos = 0;

// Отправить объявления функций, включенных в этот модуль кода:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

std::string BufferToByte(char bufferSymbol) {

    std::string str;
    char hex[3];
    unsigned char byte = (unsigned int)(unsigned char)bufferSymbol;
    sprintf_s(hex, "%02X", byte);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        str += hex[i];
    }
    
    return str;
}

int InputFile(HANDLE fileHandle,HDC hdc, SIZE size) {

    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    li.QuadPart = currentScrollPos;
    SetFilePointerEx(fileHandle, li, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);

    int bufferSize = 1024*2,readLine = 0;
    char* buffer = new char[bufferSize]; // Буфер размером 4 кб
    DWORD bytesRead;

    if (ReadFile(fileHandle, buffer, bufferSize, &bytesRead, NULL) && bytesRead > 0) {

        std::string strInput, strInputSymbol;
        int readLine = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i += 16) {

            int overflow = bytesRead - i;
            strInput += std::to_string(li.LowPart + i)+'|';

            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                if (j <= overflow) {
                    strInput += BufferToByte(buffer[j + i]) + ' ';
                    strInputSymbol += buffer[j + i];
                }
                else {
                    strInput += BufferToByte(' ') + ' ';
                }
            }
            strInput += '|' + strInputSymbol;

            TextOutA(hdc, 0, readLine += size.cy, strInput.c_str(), strInput.length());

            strInput = "";
            strInputSymbol = "";
        }
    }


    delete[] buffer;
    CloseHandle(fileHandle);

    return 0;
}

void SetFontToMono(HWND hwnd,HDC hdc)
{
    HFONT hFont = CreateFont(
        16,                 // высота шрифта
        0,                  
        0,                 
        0,                  
        FW_NORMAL,          
        FALSE,              
        FALSE,             
        FALSE,              
        DEFAULT_CHARSET,   
        OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, 
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
        DEFAULT_QUALITY,    
        FIXED_PITCH,        // фиксированная ширина символов 
        L"Courier New"      
    );

    SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Разместите код здесь.

    // Инициализация глобальных строк
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT1, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Выполнить инициализацию приложения:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT1));

    MSG msg;

    // Цикл основного сообщения:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  ЦЕЛЬ: Регистрирует класс окна.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINDOWSPROJECT1));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT1);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   ФУНКЦИЯ: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   ЦЕЛЬ: Сохраняет маркер экземпляра и создает главное окно
//
//   КОММЕНТАРИИ:
//
//        В этой функции маркер экземпляра сохраняется в глобальной переменной, а также
//        создается и выводится главное окно программы.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Сохранить маркер экземпляра в глобальной переменной

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, (WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW & ~WS_THICKFRAME),
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  ЦЕЛЬ: Обрабатывает сообщения в главном окне.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - обработать меню приложения
//  WM_PAINT    - Отрисовка главного окна
//  WM_DESTROY  - отправить сообщение о выходе и вернуться
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    long long  k;
    static long long sy, count, scrollPos = 0;
    HWND hButtonContainer;

    static SIZE sizeSymbol = { 8, 16 };
    HDC hdc;
    LPCWSTR filename = L"C:/Users/79374/Downloads/5GB.txt";
    RECT rect;

    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);
    HANDLE file = CreateFileW(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Oшибка при открытия файла", L"Ошибка", MB_OK);
    }

    LARGE_INTEGER fileSize;

    if (!GetFileSizeEx(file, &fileSize)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Oшибка при получении размера файла", L"Ошибка", MB_OK);
        CloseHandle(file);
    }

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
           // HWND textOffsetInput = CreateWindowEx(0, L"EDIT", L"Смещение", WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE,10,10, 200, 25, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
           // HWND buttonOffsetInput = CreateWindowEx(0, L"BUTTON", L"ENTER", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 50, 25, textOffsetInput, (HMENU)ID_BUTTON, NULL, NULL);

            // Создание контейнера для кнопок
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);
            hButtonContainer = CreateWindow(L"STATIC", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, 0.75*(rect.right-rect.left), 0, 0.25 * (rect.right - rect.left), rect.bottom - rect.top, hWnd, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), NULL);


        }
    break;
    case WM_SIZE:
        {
        sy = HIWORD(lParam);
        k = (fileSize.QuadPart - sy / sizeSymbol.cy)/16;
        if (k > 0) count = k; else count = scrollPos = 0;
        SetScrollRange(hWnd, SB_VERT, 0, count, FALSE);
        SetScrollPos(hWnd, SB_VERT, scrollPos, FALSE);
        }
    break;
    case WM_VSCROLL:
        {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case SB_LINEUP: scrollPos--; break;
        case SB_LINEDOWN: scrollPos++; break;
        case SB_PAGEUP: scrollPos -= sy / sizeSymbol.cy; break;
        case SB_PAGEDOWN: scrollPos += sy / sizeSymbol.cy; break;
        case SB_THUMBPOSITION: scrollPos = HIWORD(wParam); break;
        }
        scrollPos = max(0, min(scrollPos, count));
        if (scrollPos != GetScrollPos(hWnd, SB_VERT))
        {
            SetScrollPos(hWnd, SB_VERT, scrollPos, FALSE);
            currentScrollPos = scrollPos * 16;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
        }
        break;
        }
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        SetFontToMono(hWnd, hdc);
        InputFile(file, hdc, sizeSymbol);
       
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        // Отрисовка hButtonContainer
        /*RECT buttonRect;
        GetClientRect(hButtonContainer, &buttonRect);
        InvalidateRect(hButtonContainer, &buttonRect, FALSE);*/
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Разобрать выбор в меню:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Обработчик сообщений для окна "О программе".
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```